# While working with Python Decorator i saw that function returns itself, what this logically implies?

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-decorators

Say the Decorator Example is

```
def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("=======")
        func()
        print("=======")
    return wrap
```

i know a function can return any variable output say return a, return b+c , also it can return another function, but function returning itself , not able to understand this! 
Please explain as simple as you can, because i m a selflearner

Comment: There is no function returning itself in that code.

Comment: In your case, you misunderstood the way indentation works in Python. `decor` is return `wrap`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the function `wrap` returns `wrap` itself, it is not true.

Looking at the indentation, `decor` returns `wrap` and `wrap` returns `None`.

Comment: i think I misunderstood this indentation